# Recursively Replace certain characters on server (Cent0s) to import images in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, character-encoding

I have a folder for all my product images which are structured to mimic the categories. Now some of these folders, and some product images have some special characters in them. Mostly & and Ë, Now the CSV I import I can simply Find and replace these with a word or letter. But how do I do it for the actual folders so the new file paths match the actual file structure

Comment: We need more informations, exemple of csv file

Comment: For example a base image patch is pub/media/products/category/example-&-example/filenamË.jpg                So i have maybe 5 characters i need to replace but i need to do it to thousands of files and folders recursively